# com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder cannot be cast to android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder in android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, popupmenu

I've created one recycler view in `Activity` and inside the `RecyclerViewAdapter`

Following is my code snippet written in `onBindViewHolder()`:

```
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(activity,holder.ivEventShare);
popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.item_event,popupMenu.getMenu());
popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
       switch (item.getItemId()){
           case R.id.action_item_event_share:
               Toast.makeText(activity, "This Item will be shared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)show();
               break;
           }
           return true;
       }
   });

popupMenu.show();
MenuPopupHelper helper = new MenuPopupHelper(activity, (MenuBuilder) popupMenu.getMenu(),v);
helper.setForceShowIcon(true);
helper.setGravity(Gravity.END);
helper.show();
```

I've created `PopUpMenu` and I want it to show the menu with icons.

But it is showing following error:

> com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder cannot be cast to android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder

In this line:

```
MenuPopupHelper helper = new MenuPopupHelper(activity, (MenuBuilder) popupMenu.getMenu(),v);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check your imports

Comment: @SamirBhatt Imports are correct.

Comment: You're mixing support library versions of popup menu classes with standard library versions. Your imports must be all one or the other (and you may not get to choose).

Answer (score 4):

```
import android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder;
import android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper;
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;

//enter code here

imagePostShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, v);
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.share_menu, popup.getMenu());

    // popup.show();
    MenuPopupHelper menuHelper = new MenuPopupHelper(mContext, (MenuBuilder) popup.getMenu(),v);
    menuHelper.setForceShowIcon(true);
    menuHelper.show();

    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
    int id = menuItem.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.shareAsPost) {
        String postId = item.getSharedPostId();
        Call<PostShareItem> call = webService.getPostDetails(deviceId, 
                                   profileId, token, userIds, postId);
        sendShareItemRequest(call);
    }

    if (id == R.id.shareFacebook) {}
    if (id == R.id.shareTwitter) {
        Toast.makeText(App.getAppContext(), "Removed : ", 
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if (id == R.id.copyLink) {}
       return true;
    }
  });
 }
});
```

Comment: Consider adding any explanation or comment to your code.

Comment: I have changed imports like here and now it works (my own case) !

Comment: import androidx.appcompat.widget.PopupMenu;